Details in the proof of quotient manifold theorem
The theorem is stated as: Let $G$ be a Lie group acting smoothly, freely and properly on a smooth manifold $M$. Then $M/G$ is a topological manifold of dimension dim$M$ - dim$G$, and has a unique smooth structure such that $\pi:M\to M/G$ is smooth submersion. dim$G=k$, dim$M=m$, $n=m-k$.
The proof depends on the so-called $G$-adapted charts:$(U,\phi)$ is called $G$-adapted if for any $y\in M$, $\phi(Gy\cap U)\subset \{(x,c)\in R^k\times R^n|x\in R^k\}$ for some $c \in R^n$.
To see $M/G$ is locally Euclidean, $q=\pi(p)\in M/G$. $(U,\phi)$ adapted chart centered at $p$. We can assume $\phi(U)=U'\times U''$.(Shrinking $U$ if necessary and charts inside adapted chart are adapted). Let $V=\pi(U), Y=\phi^{-1}(\{0\}\times U'')$. John Lee claims that $\pi$ restricts to bijection from $Y$ to $V$ in his book "Introduction to smooth manifolds" P.546. This is where I have doubts.
The problem is with surjectivity. For $p,q \in U$, $G_p=G_q$ iff $G_p\cap U= G_q\cap U$ iff $\phi(G_p\cap U)=\phi(G_q\cap U)$. So we have injective map $h:\pi(U)\to P(U'\times U'')$ by sending $A$ to $\phi(A\cap U)$. Thus $\pi(Y)=\pi(U)$ iff $h(\pi(Y))=h(\pi(U))$. $U=\bigcup\limits_{p\in U}G_p\cap U$. $\phi(U)=\bigcup\limits_{c\in U''}\phi(U)\cap (U'\times \{c\})$= $\bigcup\limits_{c\in U''}\bigcup\limits_{\phi(G_p\cap U)\subset U'\times \{c\}}\phi(G_p\cap U)=U'\times U''$. $h(\pi(U))=\bigcup\limits_{c\in U''}\{\phi(G_p\cap U)| \phi(G_p\cap U)\subset U'\times \{c\}\}$. $h(\pi(Y))=\bigcup\limits_{c\in U''}\{\phi(G_{p_c}\cap U)\}$, where $\phi(G_{p_c}\cap U)\ni (0,c)$. Therefore $\phi(G_{p_c}\cap U)=U'\times \{c\}$ i.e there's only one orbit with image in the $c$-section for each $c$, I don't see how is this true with the conditions.
And in the next page John says “The fact that the coordinates are adapted to G-actions means that two points with the same $y$-coordinate are in the same orbit.” I haven’t read the proof about existence of adapted charts due to lack of some background, but I am starting to wonder if $G$ adapted charts just means this and that he made a typo in the proof.

I think you should get at most finitely many orbits by using that the action is free and proper and then get a single one by restricting U.

The definition of $G$-adapted chart is on page 545: it's a cubical chart $(U,\varphi)$ such that each orbit intersects $U$ either in the empty set or in a single $y=\text{constant}$ orbit.

@JackLee I know, but from the surjectivity claim it's actually equal to some constant orbit. I have no idea how to show that from the conditions.

Every element $v\in V$ is an orbit $Gq$ for some $q\in U$.  We can write the coordinate representation of $q$ as $(x,y)$. By definition of adapted chart, every point in $U$ with coordinates of the form $(x',y)$ is in the same orbit. In particular, $(0,y)$ is in $Y$ and also in the orbit $Gq$, so $\pi(0,y) = v$.

@JackLee "every point in $U$
with coordinates of the form $(x′,y)$
is in the same orbit" This sentence means for any $c \in U''$, there exists $p$ such that $\phi(G_p\cap U)=U'\times {c}.$ But again this is not the def of adapted chart as I understand and this is equivalent to $\pi(Y)=V$ in my argument.
